# Ending promise function with reject without using return or nested if, how is that possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is the structure I would like to do.

Making the error checks one-liners to make the code look more clean.

```
var findCurrency = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    currencyTable.findOne (
        { _id: userCurrency }
    ,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {reject(new Error('findCurrency: ' + err))};
        if (!data) {reject(new Error('Curreny not found"))};
        console.log("DONT GO HERE IF ERROR");
        resolve(data);
    });
})};
```

I was hoping reject would stop the Promise and return, but it does not.
When it has an error it still goes to the console.log

My only way to solve this is a big nested if structure which in some cases with many checks can become pretty big and messy.

```
var findCurrency = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    currencyTable.findOne (
        { _id: userCurrency }
    ,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(new Error('findCurrency: ' + err))
        } else {
            if (!data) {
                reject(new Error('Curreny not found"))
            } else {
        resolve(data);
            }
        }
    });
})};
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

using `return` in my fist code is not possible since this will aboart the whole controller

Comment: You should not nest `else`-`if`s in blocks.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, it does make it very messy. I got very long else - if structures in some controllers.  Do you have a suggestion to avoid these long nestings?

Comment: I mean, just don't indent them. Don't wrap the `else` statement in a block. Write `if (err) reject(…);¶ else if (!data) reject(…)¶ else resolve(data);`.

Comment: Ahhhh.... ok got you - and yes MUCH nicer to read.  I got some code polishing to do now - thanks again Bergi :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a one liner, though I cannot say it is very good for readability

```
(err && (reject(err) | true)) || (!data && (reject(new Error('Currency not found')) | true)) || resolve(data)
```

These blocks will only run if the first statement of a block is true, as soon as 1 is true, the other statements will not run anymore. This assumes that reject & resolve return undefined to give it the default value of true

Another way to rewrite your answer in a somewhat more readable way would be to use returns after rejection tags, like:

```
if (err) {
    reject(new Error('findCurrency: ' + err))
    return;
}
if (!data) {
    reject(new Error('Curreny not found'))
    return;
}
resolve(data);
```

Comment: Icepickle, that actually worked. I thought the return would end my controller. I think your last suggestion is a clean and elegant way to do it, and more readable as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard You are welcome, no `return` will only end the current executing function (eg: no statements would be run afterwards). The second suggestion is indeed a lot more elegant than the first, however, you wanted to have a one-liner ;) Also note, your code had the wrong closing bracket in the `Currency not found` error (opening with `'` closing with `"` though I believe this was rather a copy past error ;))

Answer (score 0):

I would just return the rejects in the callback function.

```
var findCurrency = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    currencyTable.findOne({ _id: userCurrency }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) return reject(new Error('findCurrency: ' + err));
        if (!data) return reject(new Error('Currency not found")) 
        resolve(data);
    });
})};
```